# How do I run Cakephp's tests (PHPUnit) and output it to QuickRun or other window?

Tags: quickfix, filetype-php

Is there a way to run tests of the current opened file and get output in other window like [vim-QuickRun](https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun) does?

Right now I'm running tests by the command in command line:

```
/vagrant/my_project/app/Console/cake test app Console/Command/FeedParseShell
```

+++UPDATE+++

I'm calling `cake` command in the project folder by absolute path, because I have several projects on my virtual machine. I'm still not aware how to make `vim` to know where is the root folder of the project It's currently in.
And then I tell CakePHP console what command I want it to run by specifying the option `test` and write the path to the test file.
It looks like this:

```
/vagrant/my_project/app/Console/cake test app Console/Command/FeedParseShell
```

(`app` is not necessary - we can specify the absolute path to the test file without `app` like:

```
/vagrant/my_project/app/Console/cake test /vagrant/my_project/app/Test/Case/Console/Command/FeedParseShell
```

)

Test files are locatedy in different folders. Here is the structure of `Test/Case` folder:

```
Console  Controller  Lib  Model  View  allTest.php
```

Comment: You might be interested in the [`vim-rooter`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter) plugin.

Comment: @muru Thank you very much for your great help. Plugin does work greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CakePHP, but you could use `:make` for it:

```
set makeprg=/vagrant/my_project/app/Console/cake\ test\ app\ Console/Command/FeedParseShell
```

Then, if you run `:make`, the output of this command will be used to populate [the quickfix list](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix) (which can be useful if the output identifies offending line numbers).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response & sorry for late acceptance, I was away from my PC for couple days ^^

Comment: @whitesiroi No problem. I had a clarification to ask: What does your general `/vagrant/my_project/app/Console/cake` usage look like? Does it change with the current file, etc.? We could come up with a more general command.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I did update my question, so please have a look at it if you have some time.