# How to run custom console command and output results to QuickRun without pressing any key on keyboard?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc

Thanks to [@muru](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6448/how-do-i-run-cakephps-tests-phpunit-and-output-it-to-quickrun-or-other-window/6450#6450) I was able to run and output the data to QuickRun by the `:make` command and this setting in my `.vimrc`:

```
set makeprg=/vagrant/my_project/app/Console/cake\ test\ app\ Console/Command/FeedParseShell
```

But I have to press `Enter` several times to get back to the `vim` editor and open the output by typing `:copen`. Is there a way to skip this steps and get the output without typing `:copen`?

Comment: Separate questions, separate posts, please. What happens if you do `:silent! make | copen`?

Comment: @muru +1 Again, thank you mate :) silent & pipe does the trick. Only one question remain - how can I run it with FindRootDirectory()? I did create separate question http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6508/how-can-i-get-path-from-vim-rooters-function-and-run-it-with-quickruns-makeprg ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with no stdin functionality, you could use [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window) entry in the Vim wikia page.

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call RunShellCommand(<q-args>)
function! RunShellCommand(cmdline)
  let isfirst = 1
  let words = []
  for word in split(a:cmdline)
    if isfirst
      let isfirst = 0
    else
      if word[0] =~ '\v[%#<]'
        let word = expand(word)
      endif
      let word = shellescape(word, 1)
    endif
    call add(words, word)
  endfor
  let expand_cmdline = join(words)
  botright new
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
  call setline(1, 'You entered: ' . a:cmdline)
  call setline(2, 'Expanded to: ' . expand_cmdline)
  call append(line('$'), substitute(getline(2), '.', '=', 'g'))
  silent execute '$read !'. expand_cmdline
  1
endfunction
```

This command is great for running an autonomous command and getting the response in its own scratch buffer. `:RunShellCommand cmake test app Console/CommandFeedParserShell` I use this for all the other non-make situations when I don't want to write the output to my current buffer (a la `:!command`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vim 8 / neovim, maybe you can try asyncrun:

https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim

as a replacement to vim-dispatch/quickrun with better user experience and expansibility.

[image]

- Easy to use, just start your background command by :AsyncRun (just like old "!" cmd).
- Command is done in the background, no need to wait for the entire process to finish.
- Output are displayed in the quickfix window, errors are matched with errorformat.
- You can explore the error output immediately or keep working in vim while executing.
- Ring the bell or play a sound to notify you job finished while you're focusing on editing.
- Fast and lightweight, just a single self-contained asyncrun.vim source file.
- Provide corresponding user experience in vim, neovim, gvim and macvim.