# How can I get path from vim-rooter's function and run it with QuickRun's makeprg?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc

How can I run vim-rooter's function `FindRootDirectory()` instead of `/vagrant/my_project`? I have tried multiple variations like:

```
set makeprg=FindRootDirectory().'/app/Console/cake test '.expand('%:p')
set makeprg=FindRootDirectory()."/app/Console/cake" test %:p
```

+++UPDATE+++

`let &makeprg=FindRootDirectory()."/app/Console/cake test %:p"` does work, but I'm also getting a black screen instead of my previous opened file. Do you know how can I get only results in the bottom?

And I'm getting this errors after running the `vim` command:

```
E117: 未知の関数です(Unknown function): FindRootDirectory
E15: 無効な式です(Invalid expression): FindRootDirectory()."/app/Console/cake test %:p"
```

+++UPDATE+++

Was able to solve it by:

```
autocmd VimEnter * let &makeprg=FindRootDirectory()."/app/Console/cake test %:p"
```

Comment: You seem to have a lot of problems with something called "QuickRun". Whatever it is, don't you think you should read that thing's documentation and/or use its issue tracker?

Comment: @romainl thank you. I read it, but didn't get it ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:let &makeprg` instead of `:set`. The latter expects an un-quoted string.

Comment: If I understood it right, this will have to be done each time OP switches to something with a different root directory, i.e, there's no way to evaluate what the root directory is when `:make` is called.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte Thank you very much. let &makeprg=FindRootDirectory()."/app/Console/cake test %:p" does work, but I'm also getting a black screen instead of my previous opened file. Do you know how can I get only results in the bottom? I attach screenshot and update my question. Thank you.

Comment: @muru I have tried with several projects and :silent! make | copen does work great.

Comment: Looks like you need to source the plugin where this function is defined before calling it.